# query on ubuntu installation in laptop

Tags: 12.04

I have a laptop with celeron dual core with 2 gb DDR2 RAM and 40 GB of hard disk. which version of ubuntu you recommend me to install for proper functioning of my laptop

Answer (score 0):

The latest Ubuntu would work. Now, if u want 2 get more time between backups and upgrading to latest version, stick to LTS.

Minimum system requirements are [here](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Installation/SystemRequirements)

Answer (score 0):

Ubuntu 12.04LTS 32-bit might be the perfect fit for your system, but Unity requires more processors power. You can have Kubuntu or Lubuntu instead.